# Изменить цвет ссылки

Tags: html, css

Учу HTML и CSS и не могу понять, почему у ссылки, у которой прописано `text-decoration:none` все равно остается цвет ссылки. Просто когда вчера писал, у меня после этого значения, цвет стал черный, а сейчас почему -то цвет нажатой ссылки.

```css
.header {
  box-shadow: black;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  /*background-color: black;*/
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
  max-height: 60px;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: table;
}

.container::before {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}

.container::after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: relative;
  /*margin: 0.3rem;*/
}

.nav__left {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  margin: 0.3rem 0px 0rem 0rem;
}

.nav__left__names {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  margin: -0.1rem 0px 0.3rem 0rem;
}

.nav__logo {
  width: 2.7rem;
  height: 2.7rem;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0.3rem 0px 0.3rem 0rem;
}

.nav__right>ul>li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  padding: 0px 10px;
}

.nav__right>ul>li>a {
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <img class="nav__logo" src="/images/logo.png" alt="Logo">
    <div class="nav">
      <div class="nav__left">
        It's name
        <div class="nav__left__names">
          My name
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--nav_left-->
      <div class="nav__right">
        <ul>
          <li><a class="main" href="#">Главная</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Скачать</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Протоколы</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!--nav__right-->
    </div>
    <!--nav-->
  </div>
  <!--container-->
</header>
<!--header-->
```

Answer (score 3):

Свойство `text-decoration` относится ведь не к цвету, так?) Он добавляет оформление текста в виде его подчеркивания, перечеркивания, линии над текстом и мигания.

Обычно цвет ссылок по-умолчанию на странице синий, подробнее об этом можно прочесть [здесь](http://htmlbook.ru/content/tsvet-ssylok)

Сменить цвет ссылки можете задав в своих стилях

```
.nav__right > ul > li > a {
    color: green; //собственно тут Ваш цвет
}
```